# Center image inside image using imagecopy function

Tags: php, image, function

I have a simple script that adds an image inside an image. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(650, 400);
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('test.png');

$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 209, 231, 244);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 133;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) 
- $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im); 

?>
```

Now this will place the test image 10x from the right of the big image and 133px from bottom of image. How to place the image centered vertically depending on its height??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$marge_right` and `$marge_bottom` should correspond to the difference of horizontal and vertical sizes (respectively) between the source and destination images.

So you need to calculate the difference this way:

```
$marge_right = abs($dest_sx-$src_sx);
$marge_bottom = abs($dest_sy-$src_sy);
```

The `abs` is optional if you are sure the source is bigger that the source is smaller than the destination.

Comment: The problem is that I can't understand the `imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right` part as I got the function from another thread. To center something we get the bigger minus the smaller and divide by 2 so can't understand how to do that in image gd as it's one of the most confusing functions in php

Comment: `imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right` supposes that you know the margin from the right and want to get the margin from the left (which is what GD uses: `(0,0)` is the top-left). But now, you don't need that, so you can just calcualte the left margin and use it directly. Also, note that when centered, `$margin_right == $margin_left`.

Comment: thanks Jad very much :) I got a so much better understanding of how this works now...also 0,0 wasn't clear that it's from top left not bottom left i as used to plot graphs

Answer (score -1):

There is that powerful tool called 5th grade math...

Since you have your height given in 
`imagecreatetruecolor(650, 400);`

and the height and width of your placed image in $sx and $sy this boils down to simple offset calculation to pass to $marge_right and $marge_bottom

Comment: There is a tool called respect too.

Comment: and congrats to you for obviously solving someones homeworks for the sake of a +1

Comment: Absolutely by your side, mightyuhu. +1 from me, and this sort of problem was narrated milions of times, so... If someone is talking about respect, please respect the community here, and don't ask what comes to your mind before trying to solve it alone / search for answer.